# How to change Y-axis in histfit plot from counts to percents? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have next plot :

h= histfit(myVec); set(gca, 'XLim', [-2 2]);ylim([0 400]); set( h (2),'color','black');

% myVec contains also  negative values

How I can change this plot to plot with Y-axis in percentages not in counts ?
Thanks so much inadvance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `histfit` doesn't have that option by default. Instead, you can combine `histogram`, `fitdist` and `pdf` to get what you want.

First you plot your data with `histogram`, normalized to the observation probability (same as percentage). Set the number of bins `nbins` to whatever you need.

```
nbins = 10; 
h = histogram(yourData, nbins, 'Normalization', 'Probability');
hold on
```

Then you use `fitdist` to generate a distribution of choice, from your data. Here I'm using a normal distribution.

```
% yourData needs to be a column vector
pd = fitdist(yourData(:), 'Normal');
```

Generate a Y value for this distribution for every point X. Set X to whatever you want. Then normalize the Y value to the total sum of the y values (equivalent to converting to a percentage), and plot it on top of the histogram.

```
x = -2:0.1:2;
y = pdf(pd, x);
y = y / sum( pdf(pd, x) );
plot(x, y, 'k--') % Plot distribution as a black dashed line
```